# Can programmers on a Swedish PC not write T-SQL queries involving variables named V and W?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, collation

I have this view source code, written on a machine with SQL Server 2012 and Latin1 server and database collation:

```
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
  W.AbteilungsNr AS Bereichsnummer,
  W.LongCap AS Bereichsname,
  convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),(SELECT MAX(V.ZeitVon) FROM mna01HSQVorfallsmeldungen V INNER JOIN mna01HSQProtokolle P ON P.[ID]=V.ProtokollID WHERE P.WS_Bereich_ID=W.[ID] AND P.Category=4 AND V.ProposedCat IN (41)),104),104) AS DatumLetzterMTC,
  convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),(SELECT MAX(V.ZeitVon) FROM mna01HSQVorfallsmeldungen V INNER JOIN mna01HSQProtokolle P ON P.[ID]=V.ProtokollID WHERE P.WS_Bereich_ID=W.[ID] AND P.Category=4 AND V.ProposedCat IN (40)),104),104) AS DatumLetzterRWC,
  convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),(SELECT MAX(V.ZeitVon) FROM mna01HSQVorfallsmeldungen V INNER JOIN mna01HSQProtokolle P ON P.[ID]=V.ProtokollID WHERE P.WS_Bereich_ID=W.[ID] AND P.Category=4 AND V.ProposedCat IN (42,44)),104),104) AS DatumLetzterLTI,
  convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),(SELECT MAX(V.ZeitVon) FROM mna01HSQVorfallsmeldungen V INNER JOIN mna01HSQProtokolle P ON P.[ID]=V.ProtokollID WHERE P.WS_Bereich_ID=W.[ID] AND P.Category=4 AND V.ProposedCat IN (40,41,42,44)),104),104) AS DatumLetzterUnfall,
  DATEDIFF(day,(SELECT MAX(V.ZeitVon) FROM mna01HSQVorfallsmeldungen V INNER JOIN mna01HSQProtokolle P ON P.[ID]=V.ProtokollID WHERE P.WS_Bereich_ID=W.[ID] AND P.Category=4 AND V.ProposedCat IN (40,41,42,44)),GETDATE()) AS TageUnfallfrei
FROM mna01HSQWerksstruktur W
WHERE W.objType=1
AND W.Reportable=1
ORDER BY 
  W.AbteilungsNr ASC
```

As you can see, this code relies on tables aliases `W` and `V` representing two different tables.
When I try to execute that on a database with collation Finnish_Swedish_CI_AI, it fails with

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure vwmna01HSQrptNoAccidentSince, Line 18
Invalid column name 'ID'
```

Now I have already done my homework and figured out, that the letters V and W are considered equal in that Swedish collation. When we use Z instead of W, it works.

My questions remain:

- Is that a bug, or has it any use that this collation rule is applied to the very source code (I understand that it needs to apply to string literals and data)
- Is there any way to prevent that from happening, some sort of SET directive, or connection property?

EDIT: It occurs in SSMS query window as well as when executed using OleDB from a .NET SqlConnection in code. It makes no difference if we execute it as a part of a `CREATE VIEW` statement, or as an ad-hoc query as shown above.

Comment: [Similiar case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/608ac8c6-cb03-43b7-8476-c52f9e53349d/sql-error-column-names-in-each-table-must-be-unique-column-name-w-in-table-table1-is?forum=transactsql)

Comment: @lad2025 somewhat similar, yes. but: table names are stored in sysobjects, and therefore subject to the collation rules. pure source code constructs like row source aliases should not. that's like you would send some C code like `int v,w;` to a Swedish colleague and he could not compile it.

Comment: Most databases I have seen here in Sweden use Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS  where this is not a problem.

Comment: really? maybe I should move this to linguistics.stackexchange.com, how does v/w relate to accent sensitivity?

Comment: Aliases use the collation ofthe current database. Executing the script from database with another collation will work differently. e.g. `USE master; SELECT ... FROM swedishdatabase..table1 AS v, swedishdatabase..table2 AS w`

Comment: @adrianm valuable information. confirms the observation that collation does apply to aliases in T-SQL code (still: why would it?). but does not help the case. I tried it, it works, basically, but I cannot use it for two reasons: a) I need to create a view and that would fail with Msg 166 CREATE/ALTER VIEW does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name. And b) I am a software vendor and they are my customer and I cannot touch their `master` database.

Comment: It was not meant as a solution to your problem. Start to use descriptive aliases instead of single letter and you'll be fine.

Comment: In fact I already did. My developers are preferably using three-character acronyms for aliases nowadays. the snippet in the Q is from a legacy db we still need to maintain (a different story) and has ~4000 views+procedures whereof 37 are affected by that particular problem. I will now have all of them rewritten, still the Q stands.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably in case sensitivity. Check your table if there is column "ID" - don't mistake with "Id". Fix your procedure.

Comment: the database collation is Finnish_Swedish_CI_AI (case insensitive, accent insensitive). problem can be narrowed down to collation equality of letters V and W already.

Comment: Yes, but collation of server is probably case sensitive.

Comment: case sensitivity has been ruled out as the cause. the problem has been reduced two test cases: test case 1: using table aliases V and W, result: error message 207; test case 2: using table aliases V and Z, result: OK.